# APK made by buildozer not making CSV file on android mobile

Tags: android, kivy, apk, csv-write-stream

I made an APK with the help of KivyApp. APK generated successfully and my APK also runs on my mobile. The problem is that I didn't give any specific path for the CSV file, which stored the output generated by the app. Initially, I run python code in the pydroid3 app and it automatically generated the CSV file at the same location, where my code was stored. My question is if I want to store the data in the internal storage of my mobile, what path should I enter?

```
import csv
csvfile = "Discrete_pos.csv"
with open(csvfile, "a") as fp:
    wr = csv.writer(fp, dialect='excel')
    wr.writerow(csvRow)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I suppose you mean the path of `External Storage` (which can be accessed by any app, one you see in your mobile file explorer) As it's already storing in your internal storage path. Now to access external storage there are 2 methods. But first of all you need storage permission for that. To get storage permission use the following code:

```
from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
request_permissions([Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE])
```

Now after you have access to external storage you can use the following code to get external storage path:

```
from android.storage import primary_external_storage_path
external_storage = primary_external_storage_path()
```

Sometimes this doesn't work on some android devices so if you are getting that issue then you can also use `os.getenv`:

```
external_storage = os.getenv('EXTERNAL_STORAGE')
```

Also, don't forget to write `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in the permissions of your `buildozer.spec` file

Comment: Thank you! my question is related to `Internal_storage`, I am giving the path like /storage/emulated/0/kivy/my.csv. for internal storage what type of permission and path required?

Comment: `/storage/emulated/0` is `External Storage` path. Internal storage path looks like `/data/data/APP_NAME` which can only be accessed by your app. So, that's why I said earlier in my answer that you are looking for external storage, not internal storage.

Comment: You need `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions for that. I have already provided code in my answer to get that permission. Code to get the path is also provided in the answer. In your `buildozer.spec` file, there will be an option saying `permissions = INTERNET` or something like that. It will be commented, just uncomment it and add `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` to it.

Comment: If that helped, please consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it and welcome to Stack!